# "No single root directory found, all dists must extract to a single directory" error when trying to upload module to zef via App::Mi6

Tags: raku, zef, fez

Getting a weird error I've never seen before while trying to upload a new module to zef using the App::Mi6 `mi6 release` command:

```
==> Step 9. UploadToZef
Are you sure you want to upload Directory-0.0.1.tar.gz to Zef ecosystem? (y/N) y
Executing /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/bin/rakudo -e use Fez::CLI --file=Directory-0.0.1.tar.gz upload
>>= Looking in "Directory-0.0.1.tar.gz" for META6.json
=<< No single root directory found, all dists must extract to a single directory
Failed
  in method upload at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/sources/12D2D4FC78FDF40E8B7DEC72AF31ECED31A67D08 (App::Mi6::Fez) line 19
  in method run at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/sources/A4949DB54562D3B5154DD447B5CC2C730F09B0E5 (App::Mi6::Release::UploadToZef) line 24
  in method run at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/sources/BDF7095037EE976677901A8557FD533DCDC6FD65 (App::Mi6::Release) line 49
  in method cmd at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/sources/299DED9746B9228495A0B5E829FE0A6BBD7DFE88 (App::Mi6) line 162
  in sub MAIN at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/resources/5831540356728593B89C55370F0C33F8DD0813F5 line 20
  in block <unit> at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/resources/5831540356728593B89C55370F0C33F8DD0813F5 line 5
  in sub MAIN at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/bin/mi6 line 3
  in block <unit> at /Users/steve/.rakubrew/versions/moar-2022.12/share/perl6/site/bin/mi6 line 1
```

Google turns up nothing on this error. This means I've found a major bug or the three glasses of wine I've had tonight have me doing something really stupid. :)

Comment: I was able to get the distribution uploaded on another mac machine. I suspect I somehow hosed my libarchive library on the original machine while trying to get a libarchive Raku module to install without error: https://github.com/frithnanth/perl6-Archive-Libarchive/issues/14

Comment: When I roll back to 2022.07 from 2022.12, things work without a hitch.

Answer (score 4):

OK, this is a bug related to how the `fez` module interacts with how tarballs are generated on a mac.

A pull request has been made to address this issue: https://github.com/tony-o/raku-fez/pull/74.

I'm not sure what accounts for things working on 2022.07 and not 2022.12 version of raku.

Comment: I note the PR has been merged. I'm wondering if fixes the problem? If not, maybe leave another comment on the PR even though it's been merged. If it does fix it maybe accept your answer?